# In Android Studio Version 3.0, I am unable to find raw folder inside the res folder

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have already created the folder inside the res directory. Out Android studio, I can easily access the raw folder but Inside the android studio, It is not displaying and I am unable to get access the files inside it.
[image]

And If I select the folder structure to project it is appearing.[image]

Comment: this is not an issue...Why do you think it is an issue

Comment: I still cannot access the data inside the raw folder.

Comment: try making it a lowercase "raw"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its, **raw instead of Raw!** 
We can use following line to access elements from raw folder.

```
getResources().openRawResource(resourceName);
```

If you are looking for read text file from raw assets then you can use following sample of code.

```
InputStream raw = context.getAssets().open("filename.txt");
Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw, "UTF8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tho I had a folder named "raw" I do have a similar issue and after a couple of restarting android studio Worked fine for me, Or else you can try this

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```